# Site wont connect to DB after changing cPanel password

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I have a client who's site is on a shared hosting platform. They want desperatly to change the password of their cPanel but when they do the site cannot connect to the database. The site's database and the cPanel share the same password so I changed it in the code but that didn't fix the problem. When we reverted to the original password the DB connected fine. So my question is. When I change the cPanel password do I then have to take other measure? Thanks.

Comment: what did you change in the code? updating the database password?

Comment: I think most hosting companies allow changing ALSO database password. Look at the part of panel that leads to list of databases and their privileges.

Comment: @innoSPG Yes ... it runs codeigniter so I changed it there. Nothing.

Comment: Can you get into a mysql prompt as root, or connect as root to db with a gui tool or phpmyadmin

Comment: What @whitelettersinblankpapers said is by far the best approach if available

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using cPanel user name and password in site mysql databases config and due to that you are getting this issues, I will suggest you please create new mysql user through cPanel and assigned full permission to that mysql user and update that in your site mysql databases config file so that when you changed your cPanel password you will not get any issues with your site.